# Как добавить символ посередине строки?

Tags: php

```
$p = 123456;
$arr1 = str_split($p);
echo $arr1[0] . $arr1[1] . $arr1[2] . '/' . $arr1[3] . $arr1[4] . $arr1[5]; 
получаем: 123/456
```

есть ещё варианты как это можно организовать?

Comment: `substr($p, 1, 3).'/'.substr($p, 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $p = 123456;

    echo substr_replace($p, '/', 3, 0);
    получаем: 123/456
```

Comment: спасибо. приму ответ через пару мин. тут ограничение походу)